# iOS - detecting how I arrived at a viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have 3 viewControllers that appear in sequence, A -> B -> C

A calls B using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerB animated:YES];
```

C calls B by

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

is there a way for B to know who called it, A or C?

thanks.

Comment: I think the question you should be asking yourself is "**WHY** does B need to know who called it?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NavigationControllers viewControllers property. To see which items are in the navigation stack.

> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

You want the view controller at index n-2.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**Edit (Added Example)**

```
NSString *previousView = NSStringFromClass([[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2)] class]);
if([previousView isEqualToString:@"SettingsViewController"]){
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get this. If the root view controller is 0 and suppose in my case it calls A, so A =1, then B =2 and C = 3. If I assume that B is n, so A is n-1 and C is n+1. This is how I understand it. So, if I come from C, there will be no n+1, as C is being popped out of the array... right?

Comment: n-2 would be the view that called B. So in your case it should show A or C. n-2 is simply the view that was previously present in other words, the view the Navigation Controller would go back to when you press the back button in the navigation bar.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that to a point of creating a code... but anyway, thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I explained it pretty poorly. I have added an example to my post which should help.

Comment: No problem, glad it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.

Make a `@property` of type `UIViewController` named `comingFrom` (or whatever you want). And when you  push it, just set it's property to the current class.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of, which I use when I reuse view controllers, is to set a property on the view controller that you can query. Alloc/init your view controller, set your property (NSString or NSInteger), and push the view. That way you can use code to query that property about who created and pushed the view.

Simple, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create some enum say ClassA and ClassC and while pushing or poping just assign that enum the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

If B calls from A, -(void)viewDidLoad{} method will be call, If B calls from C that method should not call, so you can put variable globally, and assign some value in viewDidLoad() method. And remove that value when you push C, then in viewWillAppear method you know, where it is form.